# SQL Server - remove leading and trailing zeros

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to remove leading and trailing zeros from a dataset:

```
WITH

data as (
    select 0.10 ITEM
    union all
    select -1.00
    union all
    select 0.20
    union all
    select 2.00
    union all
    select 508000015.00
)
```

So that the result resemble:

```
ITEM
.1
-1
.2
2
508000015
```

Is there a more-concise or more-efficient way to do so

```
SELECT  case
          # if item isn't an integer, trim 0 from left and right 
          when item % 1 = item then REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(item,'0',' '))),' ','0') 
          else cast(cast(item as int) as varchar) 
        end VALUE
FROM    data
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the items?

Comment: Is there a concise reason for needing no trailing zeros? Are significant digits or formatting not more important? Storing at numeric, integer, even float seem to make sense here, unless you intend as keeping it as text.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk, the vendor's database is a mix of string and numeric values of the field in question.  Moreover, the desired representation matches the UI's representation.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could also work as well:

```
WITH
data as (
    select 0.10 ITEM
    union all
    select -1.00
    union all
    select 0.20
    union all
    select 2.00
    union all
    select 508000015.00
)
SELECT  *
FROM    data as d
CROSS
APPLY   (SELECT 
                SUBSTRING(CAST(ITEM AS varchar(32)), PATINDEX('0%', CAST(ITEM AS VARCHAR(32))) + 1, LEN(ITEM))) AS f (lead0) -- remove leading 0
CROSS
APPLY   (SELECT 
                SUBSTRING(f.lead0, 1, CASE 
                                        WHEN RIGHT(f.lead0, 2) = '00' THEN LEN(f.lead0) - 3 -- remove decimal point as well
                                        WHEN RIGHT(f.lead0, 1) = '0' THEN LEN(f.lead0) - 1 
                                        ELSE LEN(f.lead0) 
                                    END)) AS s (end0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like .....

```
WITH data as (
    select 0.10 ITEM
    union all
    select -1.00
    union all
    select 0.20
    union all
    select 2.00
    union all
    select 508000015.00
)
Select CASE WHEN RIGHT( REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(ITEM,'0',' '))),' ','0'), 1) = '.'
           THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(ITEM,'0',' '))),' ','0'),'.','')
           ELSE REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(ITEM,'0',' '))),' ','0') END
from data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing the data in a [numeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187746.aspx)(12, 2) column it does not matter.  SQL Server will always present the content with 2 decimal places.

```
SELECT
    CAST(1.0 AS NUMERIC(12, 2))     AS [NoDp],
    CAST(1.0 AS NUMERIC(12, 2))     AS [1Dp],
    CAST(1.00 AS NUMERIC(12, 2))    AS [2Dp],
    CAST(1.000 AS NUMERIC(12, 2))   AS [3Dp]
;
```

Returns

```
NoDp    1Dp     2Dp     3Dp
1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00
```

If you are interested in formatting the output this is best done in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be simplier. Apologies for being a tad lazy, but I think you'll get the idea.

```
WITH data as (
 select 0.10 ITEM
 union all
 select -1.00
 union all
 select 0.20
 union all
 Select 2.00
 union all
 select 508000015.00
 union all
 select 508015
 union all
 select 50815)

set1 as (Select
case when LEN(item) > 6 then cast(cast(item as numeric) as varchar)
else cast(cast(item as float) as varchar)
end item
from data)

select
case
    when item like '0.%' then RIGHT(item,len(item)-1) else item
end As item
from set1
```